# LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH issue with Impala table

Tags: hive, impala

I have a Impala table "ca1" with following structure

```
[abcd.us.localhost.com:21000] > desc ca1;
Query: describe ca1
+-------+--------+---------+
| name  | type   | comment |
+-------+--------+---------+   
| speed | double |         |
| dist  | double |         |
+-------+--------+---------+
Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.01s
```

I want to load the data in that table using *LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH* as my file "file30a147fdbcea.txt" is present in local file system but I am getting below error while same thing works in Hive. 
**Query:**

```
[abcd.us.localhost.com:21000] > load data local inpath 
'/tmp/RtmpWPwtl0/file30a147fdbcea.txt' into table ca1;
```

> ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
>       load data local inpath '/tmp/RtmpWPwtl...
>                 ^
>       Encountered: IDENTIFIER
>       Expected: INPATH
>
> CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Can anyone help me with what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Impala is Cloudera product & its **LOAD DATA** statement only imports files from **HDFS**, not from the local filesystem.

Full syntax:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs_file_or_directory_path' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename
   [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
```

**LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH** works for Hive command-line/beeline, but NOT for Impala, though Impala writes into Hive db.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will work. change the delimiter('|') according to your text file.

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/RtmpWPwtl0/file30a147fdbcea.txt' INTO TABLE ca1 fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Comment: sasi:Thanks a lot for answering but I am still noticing error      > LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/RtmpWPwtl0/file30a153ae2e38.txt' into table c90;
Query: load DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/RtmpWPwtl0/file30a153ae2e38.txt' into table c90
ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
load DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/RtmpWPwtl...
          ^
Encountered: IDENTIFIER
Expected: INPATH

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error